# Facebook Canvas App Loading Partially

Tags: facebook, heroku, facebook-page, facebook-canvas

I have a single page FB Canvas app that is calling through the iframe a page I have hosted on Heroku.

Loading the page directly through my heroku link works no problem. However, when I try to load the page through the canvas app, it sometimes only loads half of the HTML. I need to spam refresh in order for the entire page to render correctly in the app.

I've checked my page against W3C validator and there are no syntax issues.

Is it Heroku just being slow? It loads pretty quickly when I access the url directly.

What could cause my page to just load halfway and stop?

Comment: Check the HTTP requests that are happening using Firebug or something.

Comment: I have just this issue, did you ever find a solution? The HTTP POST request shows up as 200 in the heroku logs but firebug/web console shows the request as `HTTP 200` *and* `failed`.

Comment: Can you share the link of your app, both - canvas link and app link

Comment: Issue is not restricted to canvas, pure app reproduces the error except on some requests for no apparent reason: https://apps.facebook.com/statoil-jobs/

Comment: Well its loading completing at my end

Comment: @Sahil How many times did you reload the app? For me it loads completely about 1/10 of the times, usually when I haven't loaded the page recently.

Comment: But for me it loads completely everytime. It's showing me an image and a long list with the last li: `Location
Mölndal, Västra Götaland`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22443/discussion-between-joar-and-sahil)

Comment: Have you tried other browsers? Is this happening on all your browsers?

Comment: is it in sandbox mode, some really weird stuff happens in sandbox mode

Comment: Try http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/47/

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue while using Heroku, but only for me and a colleague which were associated to the app as owner and tester respectively, other accounts could load the page just fine.

Testing the same app hosted via [pagekite](http://pagekite.me) over a 24/3 ADSL works perfectly.

HTTPS or HTTP doesn't seem to matter. I'd say this is an Heroku issue.

---

EDIT: I'm not sure what happened, but the problem isn't there anymore. I can't think of anything that I did that fixed the issue, but I did many things both before and after the problem went away, such as cacheing remote data in the DB, and whatnot. I can't be certain anything of that helped or if it's some hidden issue in the Heroku infrastructure.

I contacted Heroku about the issue, by the time they came back to me, the issue had suddenly disappeared.

I have promised to get back with logs (both application and client HTTP/TCP logs), if you have this issue and can reproduce it, capture the logs and send it to [Heroku support](https://help.heroku.com/). Capturing TCP traffic can be done with [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and the Heroku application logs are available via `heroku logs`.

Comment: When I was experiencing this problem, other users apart from the application owner had the same problem. I concluded that it was simply the response from the server being slow. I was hosting it on heroku for what its worth.

Comment: @super9 I too use heroku for the hosting of the application, but I haven't been able to reproduce it with any users not connected to the app.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, too. I think it is related to the issue in this question: [iFrame showing up Blank in Facebook Canvas App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056283/iframe-showing-up-blank-in-facebook-canvas-app)

If it is a Python app using Flask try this code:
from werkzeug.wsgi import LimitedStream

```
class StreamConsumingMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        stream = LimitedStream(environ['wsgi.input'],
                               int(environ['CONTENT_LENGTH'] or 0))
        environ['wsgi.input'] = stream
        app_iter = self.app(environ, start_response)
        try:
            stream.exhaust()
            for event in app_iter:
                yield event
        finally:
            if hasattr(app_iter, 'close'):
                app_iter.close()
```

Active it with this line:

```
app.wsgi_app = StreamConsumingMiddleware(app.wsgi_app)
```

Source: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/47/